# Javascript Thousand Separator / string format

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, format

Is there any function in Javascript for formatting number and strings ?

I am looking for a way for thousand separator for string or numbers...
(Like String.Format In c#)

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/248039-formatcurrency-equiv

Comment: I think you'll find what you need in there :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format

Comment: `How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 239, accepted):

The reference cited in the original answer below was wrong.  There *is* a built in function for this, which is exactly what [kaiser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376483/kaiser) suggests below: `toLocaleString`

So you can do:

```
(1234567.89).toLocaleString('en')              // for numeric input
parseFloat("1234567.89").toLocaleString('en')  // for string input
```

The function implemented below works, too, but simply isn't necessary.

(I thought perhaps I'd get lucky and find out that it *was* necessary back in 2010, but no.  According to this [more reliable reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), toLocaleString has been part of the standard since ECMAScript 3rd Edition [1999], which I believe means it would have been supported as far back as IE 5.5.)

---

**Original Answer**

According to [this reference](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html#addcommas) there isn't a built in function for adding commas to a number.  But that page includes an example of how to code it yourself:

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

**Edit:**
To go the other way (convert string with commas to number), you could do something like this:

```
parseFloat("1,234,567.89".replace(/,/g,''))
```

Comment: Really Really Appreciate It // But How Can i Convert that string (with commas) to a number ?

Comment: this function breaks for numbers greater than 100,000

Comment: @DevZer0 no it doesn't

Comment: works with pure javascript + single regex replace  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324879/681830

Comment: the original answer provides you with more control when the toLocaleString method does not behave as you need it

Comment: use `(1234567).toLocaleString().replace(/,/g," ",)` for spaces between thousands

Comment: Keep in mind that toLocaleString is very slow (7 times slower than regex). Using regex is also slow in comparison to a simple loop. So if you need to use it a lot you would be better of with a simple loop (reading the number end to start). Benchmark example with quick 5 minute code: http://jsben.ch/rijTV

Comment: **Keep in mind that `toLocaleString` is implementation specific - you will get different results across browsers/environments.**

Comment: var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
nf.format(number); // "1,234,567,890"

Answer (score 138):

If is about **localizing** thousands separators, delimiters and decimal separators, go with the following:

```
// --> numObj.toLocaleString( [locales [, options] ] )
parseInt( number ).toLocaleString();
```

There are several options you can use (and even locales with fallbacks):

```js
number = 123456.7089;

result  = parseInt( number ).toLocaleString() + "<br>";
result += number.toLocaleString( 'de-DE' ) + "<br>";
result += number.toLocaleString( 'ar-EG' ) + "<br>";
result += number.toLocaleString( 'ja-JP', { 
  style           : 'currency',
  currency        : 'JPY',
  currencyDisplay : 'symbol',
  useGrouping     : true
} ) + "<br>";
result += number.toLocaleString( [ 'jav', 'en' ], { 
  localeMatcher            : 'lookup',
  style                    : 'decimal',
  minimumIntegerDigits     : 2,
  minimumFractionDigits    : 2,
  maximumFractionDigits    : 3,
  minimumSignificantDigits : 2,
  maximumSignificantDigits : 3
} ) + "<br>";

var el = document.getElementById( 'result' );
el.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Details on the [MDN info page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

**Edit:** Commentor [@I like Serena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format/19840881?noredirect=1#comment52945067_19840881) adds the following:

> To support browsers with a non-English locale where we still want English formatting, use `value.toLocaleString('en')`. Also works for floating point.

Comment: This not cover float nums.. you can change parseInt to parseFloat, but if yourInt = "100,12" (comma as decimal separator) this will fail. This can be fixed with a replace(",",".").. but will fail again with "1.000,12". So... You MUST reinvent the wheel sometimes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/1028304

Comment: Does not work well. Uses comma while at our locale space is common for thousands separator.

Comment: Shame that toLocaleString() doesn't work correctly in Safari 8 (and possibly older). (1000).toLocaleString() returns "1000" rather than the expected "1,000".

Comment: You can pass a locale to getLocaleString(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: This would be more appropriate: `Number(yourNumberOrString).toLocaleString()`

Comment: To support browsers with a non-English locale where we still want English formatting, use `value.toLocaleString('en')`. Also works for floating point.

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin _What exactly_ does not work on Safari (and on which OS and in which version)?

Comment: FYI, For India number format like ```7,77,77,777```, use ```value.toLocaleString('en-IN')```

Answer (score 48):

> Updated using look-behind support in line with ECMAScript2018 changes.
>   For backwards compatibility, scroll further down to see the original solution.

A regular expression may be used - notably useful in dealing with big numbers stored as strings.

```js
const format = num => 
    String(num).replace(/(?<!\..*)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, '$1,')

;[
    format(100),                           // "100"
    format(1000),                          // "1,000"
    format(1e10),                          // "10,000,000,000"  
    format(1000.001001),                   // "1,000.001001"
    format('100000000000000.001001001001') // "100,000,000,000,000.001001001001
]
    .forEach(n => console.log(n))
```

[» Verbose regex explanation (regex101.com)](https://regex101.com/r/wLHdGd/1)
[image: flow diagram]

---

> This original answer may not be required but can be used for backwards compatibility.

Attempting to handle this with a single regular expression *(without callback)* my current ability fails me for lack of a negative look-behind in Javascript... never the less here's another concise alternative that works in most general cases - accounting for any decimal point by ignoring matches where the index of the match appears after the index of a period.

```js
const format = num => {
    const n = String(num),
          p = n.indexOf('.')
    return n.replace(
        /\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g,
        (m, i) => p < 0 || i < p ? `${m},` : m
    )
}

;[
    format(100),                           // "100"
    format(1000),                          // "1,000"
    format(1e10),                          // "10,000,000,000"  
    format(1000.001001),                   // "1,000.001001"
    format('100000000000000.001001001001') // "100,000,000,000,000.001001001001
]
    .forEach(n => console.log(n))
```

[» Verbose regex explanation (regex101.com)](http://regex101.com/r/zB0gP7/1)

[image: flow diagram]

Comment: Has this syntax diagram been created on regex101.com?

Comment: what happen with numbers with decimals?

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name". On React Native 0.59 doing this but that really shouldn't affect RegEx.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter It'll be the use of look-behind which at time of writing is not yet supported across all platforms. I'm guessing you're referring specifically to iOS - as Safari still fails for me too. It may be best to stick with the backward compatible version for now. I was just trying to future-proof my answer. 
https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind

Comment: @Emissary Thanks for the tip. Yeah, it's on React Native 0.59 / Android, which uses a relatively older version of JavaScriptCore (JSC). I'll try again after we update to React Native 0.60+, which includes an update to the JSC.

Comment: Not working in edge, it's giving  "Unexpected quantifier"

Comment: @LeadDeveloper It works in the latest version (79 / 80) - literally only introduced in the last month or so.  Maybe try forcing a browser update?

Answer (score 11):

There's a nice jQuery number plugin: https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number

It allows you to change any number in the format you like, with options for decimal digits and separator characters for decimal and thousand:

```
$.number(12345.4556, 2);          // -> 12,345.46
$.number(12345.4556, 3, ',', ' ') // -> 12 345,456
```

You can use it inside input fields directly, which is nicer, using same options like above:

```
$("input").number(true, 2);
```

Or you can apply to a whole set of DOM elements using selector:

```
$('span.number').number(true, 2);
```

Comment: best solution imho

Comment: I don't think so, adding a new file requirement with almost 800 lines , it is like kill an ant with a granade

Answer (score 7):

I use this:

```
function numberWithCommas(number) {
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/2439715)

Comment: `'123452343267.0505'.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
"123,452,343,267.0,505"` - notice that last comma after the decimal point.

Answer (score 6):

```
var number = 35002343;

console.log(number.toLocaleString());
```

for the reference you can check here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: hahaha try this
var n = 4720
console.log(n.toLocaleString())
it wont work

Answer (score 5):

```
// thousand separates a digit-only string using commas
// by element:  onkeyup = "ThousandSeparate(this)"
// by ID:       onkeyup = "ThousandSeparate('txt1','lbl1')"
function ThousandSeparate()
{
    if (arguments.length == 1)
    {
        var V = arguments[0].value;
        V = V.replace(/,/g,'');
        var R = new RegExp('(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})'); 
        while(R.test(V))
        {
            V = V.replace(R, '$1,$2');
        }
        arguments[0].value = V;
    }
    else  if ( arguments.length == 2)
    {
        var V = document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value;
        var R = new RegExp('(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})'); 
        while(R.test(V))
        {
            V = V.replace(R, '$1,$2');
        }
        document.getElementById(arguments[1]).innerHTML = V;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP.js has a function to do this called [number_format](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481). If you are familiar with PHP it works [exactly the same way](http://php.net/number_format).

Comment: The first link follows to JS implementation of PHP's version. It's useful.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is just really [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
123000.9123.toLocaleString()
//result will be "123,000.912"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it depends on your platform. Some have a `toLocaleString()` which does not add the commas, or lacks other features in the standard. It's easy to check for `toLocaleString` presence but not to check for its compliance.

Comment: try with a number between 1000 and 9999

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript. below are the code, it will only `accept` numeric and one `dot`

> here is the javascript

```
<script >

            function FormatCurrency(ctrl) {
                //Check if arrow keys are pressed - we want to allow navigation around textbox using arrow keys
                if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40) {
                    return;
                }

                var val = ctrl.value;

                val = val.replace(/,/g, "")
                ctrl.value = "";
                val += '';
                x = val.split('.');
                x1 = x[0];
                x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';

                var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

                while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
                }

                ctrl.value = x1 + x2;
            }

            function CheckNumeric() {
                return event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 || event.keyCode == 46;
            }

  </script>
```

> HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()" onkeyup="FormatCurrency(this)" />
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/awtszs/rapc69uq/)

Answer (score 3):

```
number = 123456.7089;
result = parseInt( number ).toLocaleString() + "<br>";
result = number.toLocaleString( 'pt-BR' ) + "<br>";

var el = document.getElementById( 'result' );
el.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please add some description as well so that op and other people can understand that how this code actually solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: try with a nomber beteen 1000 and 9999

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, decimalSeparator = '.', thousandsSeparator = ',') {
  const roundedNumber = number.toFixed(decimals);
  let integerPart = '',
    fractionalPart = '';
  if (decimals == 0) {
    integerPart = roundedNumber;
    decimalSeparator = '';
  } else {
    let numberParts = roundedNumber.split('.');
    integerPart = numberParts[0];
    fractionalPart = numberParts[1];
  }
  integerPart = integerPart.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, `$1${thousandsSeparator}`);
  return `${integerPart}${decimalSeparator}${fractionalPart}`;
}

// Use Example

let min = 1556454.0001;
let max = 15556982.9999;

console.time('number format');
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  let randomNumber = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  let formated = format(randomNumber, 4, ',', '.'); // formated number

  console.log('number: ', randomNumber, '; formated: ', formated);
}
console.timeEnd('number format');
```

Comment: Don't make it so confusing. just use toLocaleString(). More information in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: @sajadsaderi I also use toLocaleString () friend, but this function doesn't give me much flexibility, so I don't have to be dealing with regional abbreviations and someone else could use it since the definition of this function is identical to the number_format () function of php.

Answer (score 1):

Combination of solutions for react

```
  let converter = Intl.NumberFormat();
  let salary =  monthlySalary.replace(/,/g,'')
  console.log(converter.format(salary))
  
  this.setState({
    monthlySalary: converter.format(salary)
  })
}

handleOnChangeMonthlySalary(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not like any of the answers here, so I created a function that worked for me.  Just want to share in case anyone else finds it useful.

```
function getFormattedCurrency(num) {
    num = num.toFixed(2)
    var cents = (num - Math.floor(num)).toFixed(2);
    return Math.floor(num).toLocaleString() + '.' + cents.split('.')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngx-format-field. It is a directive to format the input value which will appear in the view. It will not manipulate the Input value which will be saved in the backend. See link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-format-field)!

Example:

```
component.html:

<input type="text" formControlName="currency" [appFormatFields]="CURRENCY"
(change)="onChangeCurrency()">

component.ts

onChangeCurrency() {
this.currency.patchValue(this.currency.value);
}
```

To see the demo: [here](https://angular-ydfct6.stackblitz.io/)!