# Enhancing regex of thousands separator?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, separator

I saw this beautiful script to add thousands separator to js numbers:

```
function thousandSeparator(n, sep)
{
    var sRegExp = new RegExp('(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})'),
        sValue = n + '';
    if(sep === undefined)
    {
        sep = ',';
    }
    while(sRegExp.test(sValue))
    {
        sValue = sValue.replace(sRegExp, '$1' + sep + '$2');
    }
    return sValue;
}
```

usage :

```
thousandSeparator(5000000.125, '\,') //"5,000,000.125"
```

However I'm having a trouble accepting the *while loop*.

I was thinking to change the regex to : `'(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})*'` *asterisk*...

but now , how can I apply the replace statement ?

now I will  have `$1` and `$2..$n`

how can I enhance the replace func?

*p.s. the code is taken from here http://www.grumelo.com/2009/04/06/thousand-separator-in-javascript/*

Comment: Btw, it fails on `5000000.125678` -> `5,000,000.125,678`

Comment: @zerkms yep you right. http://www.grumelo.com/2009/04/06/thousand-separator-in-javascript/

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format) - there's a link [to an example](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html#addcommas) of how to do what you're trying.

Comment: @RobI again , it still has a while loop. i think a better solution can be found....( or not) ...:)

Comment: @Cylian i think we need positive look ahead `(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})(?=\.)` but it not working... i mean - only replace numbers which in their right theres a DOT.

Comment: @zerkms how can i make this work only on the left side ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption

> now i will have $1 and $2..$n

is wrong. You have two groups, because you have two sets of brackets.

```
    (-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})*
1.  ^^^^^^^^^^
2.            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And then you **repeat** the second group. If it matches the second time, it overwrites the result of the first match, when it matches the third time, it overwrites ...

That means when matching is complete, `$2` contains the value of the last match of that group.

**First approach**

```
(\d)(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+\b)
```

and replace with

```
$1,
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30vem)

It has the flaw that it does insert the comma also on the right of the dot. (I am working on it.)

**Second approach**

```
(\d)(?:(?=\d+(?=[^\d.]))(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+\b)|(?=\d+(?=\.))(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?=\.)))
```

and replace with

```
$1,
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30vev)

So now its getting a bit more complicated.

```
(\d)                   # Match a digit (will be reinserted)
(?:
    (?=\d+(?=[^\d.]))  # Use this alternative if there is no fractional part in the digit
    (?=(?:\d{3})+      # Check that there are always multiples of 3 digits ahead
    \b)                # Till a word boundary
    |                  # OR
    (?=\d+(?=\.))      # There is a fractional part
    (?=(?:\d{3})+      # Check that there are always multiples of 3 digits ahead
    (?=\.))            # Till a dot
)
```

**Problem:**
does also match the fractional part if there is not the end of the string following.

Comment: hi stema , yeah you right. but as you can see im facing 2 problems. it does considers numebers from the right 123.1234567 and i need to get rid of the while loop

Comment: @RoyiNamir I extended my answer, but so far only for the second problem. The first is still a problem.

Comment: @stema looking good, if you can fix up that part to the right I just lost a bet with myself.

Comment: @ggg you will own yourself 5 $

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think I found a solution, please test it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, it works only if there is the end of the string after the fractional part. At the moment I don't know a solution, JavaScript Regex is too limited. I am not sure how you want to use it, if you only give the number and it ends with the end of string, this should work.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to use replace, you can just add `toLocaleString` instead:

```
console.log((5000000.125).toLocaleString('en'));
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Thanks . really nice. I've would've select this answer unless i've written [regex] in tags

Comment: the other guy put a lot of effort into his answer, so he deserves the accept anyway ;) - but you really should not use regex for this, the native way is better (and easier to understand).

Comment: You can be sure I'll use it from now :)

Comment: @luschen I feel like such a noob for not knowing this one.  I feel like I've written regex so many times to do this, but based on me being on this post I also always clearly screw it up every-time and have to google it again.  This one I might not forget though ... plus localisation, yay!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly script to contrast your beautiful script.

```
10000000.0001 .toString().split('').reverse().join('')
.replace(/(\d{3}(?!.*\.|$))/g, '$1,').split('').reverse().join('')
```

Since we don't have lookbehinds, we can cheat by reversing the string and using lookaheads instead.

Here it is again in a more palatable form.

```
function thousandSeparator(n, sep) {

    function reverse(text) {
        return text.split('').reverse().join('');
    }

    var rx = /(\d{3}(?!.*\.|$))/g;

    if (!sep) {
        sep = ',';
    }

    return reverse(reverse(n.toString()).replace(rx, '$1' + sep));

}
```

Comment: do i need to download winrar to use this code ? lol ( very long)...:) thanks

Comment: @RoyiNamir what do you think of the cleaned up version? Reversing the string not doing it for you?

Comment: ive tested it in jsperf and its very slow ( compare to the main sample - which is not working with commas at the right..) i need to fix my solution so it first : get only numbers from the right , second : remove the while loop.

Comment: @RoyiNamir well this does fix both of those things, but I don't doubt that it's slow to reverse the string like this... I think lookarounds may be slow as well. Curious to see what others come up with.

Comment: i think we need to do the first phase first... how to make it work only on the left numbers...

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
result = "1235423.125".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') //1,235,423.125
```

Comment: Try this : `"1235423.12342345".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')  // "1,235,423.12,342,345"`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
result = subject.replace(/([0-9]+?)([0-9]{3})(?=.*?\.|$)/mg, "$1,$2");
```

Test [here](http://regexr.com?30ve4)

Comment: Nice one, but it puts commas in the part to the right of the decimal as well :(

Comment: `123456.134'.replace(/([0-9]+?)([0-9]{3})(?=.*?\.|$)/mg, "$1,$2")` yield :`"1,23456.134"`