# Separate a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Thousand Separator / string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format)

My question is: How can i separate a number `/1000`;
So i want to make `"1243234"` to `"1 243 234"`
or `"1000"` to `"1 000"` etc.
(sorry for my english=/)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809136/how-to-format-numbers-with-white-spaces-between-thousands

Comment: you've got to be a little more specific, do you want to place the separator where the dots should be?

Comment: IMHO, this question isn't a duplication of the provided one.

Comment: @sp00m: In my original comment, I had provided more links. The best dupe I've found (after voting) is [How to print a number thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2901102/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

```
> "1243234".replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$& ")
"1 243 234"
```