# Javascript regex: format money

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the following function to format numbers:

```
function formatNumber(value, precision) {
    if (Number.isFinite(value)) {
        // Source: kalisjoshua's comment to VisioN's answer in the following stackoverflow question:
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript
        return value.toFixed(precision || 0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)/g, "$1,")
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

The above works except one case:

```
1130.000200 becomes 1,130.000,200
```

but I need

```
1130.000200 become 1,130.000200
```

It seems I need negative lookbehind `?<!`, i.e. match a digit not preceded by dot, but how?

EDIT: As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format), Number.prototype.toLocaleString() is a good solution for newer browsers. I need to support IE10, so leave this question as it is here.

Comment: I recommend you the lib [wNumb.js](https://refreshless.com/wnumb/), to format number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Thousand Separator / string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format)

Comment: Use `Intl.NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple function to format your decimal numbers:

```
function fmt(num) {
   // split into two; integer and fraction part
   var arr = num.match(/^(\d+)((?:\.\d+)?)$/);

   // format integer part and append fraction part
   return arr[1].replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,') + arr[2];
}

var s1 = fmt('1130.000200')
//=> "1,130.000200"

var s2 = fmt('1130000200')
//=> "1,130,000,200"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `?` in after the `.`Match. updated pattern is `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)$)/g,`

> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as
>   possible, giving back as needed

[**Demo regex and explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/8uuNaV/1)

```js
console.log('1130.000200'.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)$)/g, "$1,"))
```

Comment: You're right in the example I gave, but it won't match integers.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work with code below.

The key is to match decimal point which is variable `d`. If not matches, don't replace.

```js
function formatNumber(value, precision) {
    var regex = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:(\.)\d+)?$)/g;
    return (+value).toFixed(precision || 0).replace(regex, function(a, b, c, d) {
            return d ? b+',' : b;
        });
}

console.log(formatNumber(1130.000200, 6));
console.log(formatNumber(1130, 6));
```

Example from regex101, you'll see decimal point matches into Group 3. https://regex101.com/r/qxriNx/1

Comment: Got upvote once, and downvote once. Leave a comment please so I can improve my answer.