# Replace thousand separator on websites for a user

Tags: javascript, web, separator

As a user I would like to see space ' ' thousand separator instead of a comma or 
dot on any website that I encounter in a browser. Is it possible to implement something like that perhaps with a user JS (using Tampermonkey, Greasemonkey etc..)?

e.g. **1,234,567** or **1.234.567** change to **1 234 567**

Comment: You would have to differentiate between thousands separators and decimal points somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Thousand Separator / string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx `/[,.]/g` to `replace()` those characters with space character. Try the following way:

```js
function formatStr(str){
  str = str.replace(/[,.]/g, ' ');
  return str 
}

console.log(formatStr('1,234,567'));
console.log(formatStr('1.234.567'));
```