# Simple multiplication calculator with thousand separator

Tags: javascript, html, converters, currency, multiplication

This is a simple multiplication calculator which multiplies box 1 value x box 2 value and produce the result. What I'm trying to achieve is all the three boxes should add thousand separators while retaining the decimal part.

If I type 1000 in box 1 or 2 it should auto convert as 1,000

For example: 1232323 x 23 should be as 1,232,323 x 23 = 28,343,429

```js
 function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  result.value = myResult;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format.

Comment: There might be many similar questions but that is not specific to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please explain your question clearly

Comment: Please see the answer below. The calculator should add comma separated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as an answer.

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = updateValue('box1');
  var myBox2 = updateValue('box2');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  adTextRes('result', myResult)
}

function updateValue(nameOf) {
  var inputNo = document.getElementById(nameOf).value;
  var no = createNo(inputNo);
  adTextRes(nameOf, no);
  return no;
}

function adTextRes(nameOf, no) {
  var asText = String(no).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById(nameOf).value = asText;
}

function createNo(textin) {
  return Number(textin.replace(/,/g, ""));
}
```

```html
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is close enough. Only thing is the above fields not accepting decimal values like this 6,447.95.

Comment: Is it possible to retain the decimal part?

Comment: Copy pasting works but can't type in decimal values. If you please fix that; it would be great.