# How format with commas in jQuery-UI slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Here I've used jquery-ui.js so that it shows numbers from 0 to 2000000 and I'd like to show long number  formatted like 2,000,000

```
<div class="slider>
<a id="minamount" style="">0</a>
<a id="maxamount" style="">2000000</a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 2000000,
            values: [0, 2000000],
            range: true,

            step: 10,

            slide: function (event, ui) {
               $("#minamount").html(ui.values[0]);
               $("#maxamount").html(ui.values[1]);
            }
});
```

Comment: no one can help me؟؟؟

Comment: Trying to find a duplicate for `.html(ui.values[0].toLocaleString())`

Comment: TBH your question is a bit confusing as you ask how to submit "3 digits" and in "MVC" - when you want to format a number with commas in jquery-ui.  Nothing to do with submitting/MVC and "commas" are not "digits" (eg 1.000).  Assumed it's a language barrier and tweaked the question/title

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-do-i-format-numbers-using-javascript

Comment: yes,but i can't find the answer

Comment: I literally gave you the answer above:  change `$("#minamount").html(ui.values[0]);` to `$("#minamount").html(ui.values[0].toLocaleString());`

Comment: that's not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format) for doing it like -

```
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat();
$(".slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 2000000,
            values: [0, 2000000],
            range: true,

            step: 10,

            slide: function (event, ui) {
               $("#minamount").html(numberFormat.format(ui.values[0]));
               $("#maxamount").html(numberFormat.format(ui.values[1]));
            }
});
```

You can pass a bunch of values for your locale according to the documentation if you want it formatted according to a specific locale.

Note: On the initial load, the `slide` function is not called, in which case, you could manually call the `slider('values')` function of the slider after initialization to manually set the HTML in the beginning.

**EDIT**:

Find a [sample Fiddle to play around](http://jsfiddle.net/fgm92xzr/2/)

Comment: i have question that related to it,How can I read the selected numbers??to use in other function in script.

Comment: for example i use                                                                                                       var maxamount = $("#maxamount").text();                                                                                       to read max amount.

Comment: i mean is it true ?with no comma.                                                                             
 var minamount = $("#slider-value").html(ui.values[0])}

Comment: If at that point, you have the slider already initialized, then `$(".slider").slider('values')` should give you the min and max values in an array.

Comment: you mean var minamount=$("#slider").slider('ui.values[0]'); retun me min amount in another script function,thank.

Comment: `minamount = $(".slider").slider('values')[0]` and `maxamount = $(".slider").slider('values')[1]`

Comment: how can i Read the most and the most?

Comment: i write it but it doesn't work true                                                                                  var minamount = $("#slider-value").html(values[0]);
 var maxamount = $("#slider-value").html(values[1]);

Comment: You should ask a new question for that with your complete setup.

Comment: i asked can help me?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819594/read-price-suffering-values

Answer (score 1):

To format a string using thousands separator (eg `12,345`) you can use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```
$("#minamount").html(ui.values[0].toLocaleString());
```

See snippet below.

```js
for (var i = 1.234; i < 10000000; i *= 10)
{  
  console.log(i.toLocaleString());
}
```

Comment: @sepide725 please explain what you want then. how do you want it formatted? what's wrong with my answer? I can only help if you explain what the problem is.

Comment: I have a price range with jquery-ui.js  from 3 to 5,000,000.

Comment: i want to separate numbers bigger than three digits with comma

Comment: but it writes 5000000 with no comma

Comment: i explain it for example