# Read Price Suffering Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Got the price range with the ui jquery plugin.I want to read the lowest and highest price range in javascript i used these codes.But it does not read minamout and maxamount. How can I read minamount and maxamount correctly.i want to use them in another function in script.

```
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <p> <span id="slider-value"></span></p>



        <script>

        const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat();
        $("#slider").slider(
            {
                range: true,
                values: [1000, 4005000],
                min: 1000,
                max: 4005000,
                step: 10000,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log(ui);
                    $("#slider-value").html(`${numberFormat.format(ui.values[0])} تومان  —   ${numberFormat.format(ui.values[1])}تومان`);


                }
            }
        );
        var values = $('#slider').slider('values');
        $("#slider-value").html(` ${numberFormat.format(values[0])} تومان  —     ${numberFormat.format(values[1])}تومان`);

         var minamount = $("#slider-value").html(values[0]);
        var maxamount = $("#slider-value").html(values[1]);



    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: which slider plugin you are using? Can you create working example and reproduce the issue?

Comment: using jquery-ui

Comment: that work like it,but i want Read the most and the most

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fgm92xzr/2/

Comment: your jsfiddle looks like working as expected, i did not get what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: do you want to set minamount and maxamount values on slider when page loads?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You can read min and max values inside `slide` event handler of the slider and use `$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "values" )` to read values.

you can create array of min amount and max amount values and set it to slider

see below code

```js
$(function(){
var minAmount = 1000;
var maxAmount = 4005000;
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat();
        $("#slider").slider(
            {
                range: true,
                values: [1000, 4005000],
                min: 1000,
                max: 4005000,
                step: 10000,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                     var values = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "values" );
                     $('#min').html(values[0]);
                     $('#max').html(values[1]);
                // set min and max values in variable which you can read to any other function
                minAmount = values[0];
                maxAmount = values[1];
                }
            }
        );
     // push min and max values and set it to slider
     var min = 200000;
     var max = 3100000;
     var valuesArray = [min, max];
     $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "values", valuesArray );
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="min"></div>
  <div id="max"></div>
```

Comment: The values ​​change in the slider,I want to read the lowest and highest value in the script

Comment: i want to use min and max in another function in script,and min and max value Only change in the slider,i don't have any div for them.

Comment: You can declare variable (like minAmount and maxAmount in my updated post) and use it anywhere in the script. See my updated answer.