# Converting Json response into comma separated (thousands) - Angular 5 - ES6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

Is that any elegant way to convert json response into comma separated number (for showing currency purpose).

This is what I have so far:

```
let data = {      
   "business":{        
      "trasactionTableData":[  
         {  
            "Date":"2019-08-19T00:00:00",
            "Item Details":"Plastic - Grade A",
            "slotShare":"30",
            "assetBeforeonMarket":"24.000000",
            "profitAfterSales":"0.000000",
            "actualProfit":"22",
            "actualAmount":"USD 10.00"
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2019-08-19T00:00:00",
            "Item Details":"Cashless for Cash",
            "slotShare":"32",
            "assetBeforeonMarket":"60.000000",
            "profitAfterSales":"60.000000",
            "actualProfit":"0",
            "actualAmount":"USD 7400.10"
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2019-08-19T00:00:00",
            "Item Details":"Cashless for Cash",
            "slotShare":"33",
            "assetBeforeonMarket":"81.000000",
            "profitAfterSales":"81.000000",
            "actualProfit":"0",
            "actualAmount":"USD 200.59"
         }
      ],      
   }
}


 for (let i = 0; i < data.trasactionTableData.length; i++) {
        let slotShare = this.eosTblData[i].slotShare;
        let actualAmount = this.eosTblData[i].actualAmount;
        /*
    // need to convert below as well
    let assetBeforeonMarket = this.eosTblData[i].assetBeforeonMarket;
        let profitAfterSales = this.eosTblData[i].profitAfterSales;*/

        console.log('before convert', slotShare, 'After convert', String(slotShare).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,'$1,'));
    }
```

but what I'm getting is **before convert 24.000000 After convert 24.,000,000**

Expected result for this example:

```
566,556,00
```

How to approach this in elegant way to achieve this conversion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Thousand Separator / string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format)

Comment: Use the [currency pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) : it doesn't change your data but displays it as you want

Comment: @dince12 this answer is suited for JS, Angular has another way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toLocalString` to format your number.

e.g.:

```js
const number = 5000;
const localeNumber =  number.toLocaleString('en-GB');
console.log(localeNumber); // log 5,000
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. If you just want to show the currency formatted, without changing its value, you can use the [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe), like this:

```html
    <p>{{ value | currency:'USD' }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the number pipe instead.

To give an example:

```
{{ '1234567' | number:'.2'}}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvhcrj)**

Comment: could you pls tell me how to convert this. "actualAmount":"USD 200.59"

Comment: what is the input and output?

Comment: i've already given my json structure. could you look into that? . well that's why i tried to loop through. anyways am faild

Comment: you want to convert  "actualAmount":"USD 200.59" to what?

Comment: say like .. same as USD 123,345,67.00

Comment: dude! tell me how do you want the output for USD 200.59

Comment: dude forget about that. lets assume , 'USD 2560.99.' to USD 2,560.99. hope im right :(

Comment: Yeah accept this. but have to talk to Back end guys to change the data structure

Comment: bascially . i getting value for different currency format. but in Back end they could able to decimal point only. so they ask FE team to do comma separation . this is what im working on